# Overflow difference between Chrome and Edge

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow

I notice a difference between Chrome and Edge concerning overflow behavior.

As you can see running the following code, in Chrome this shows only the vertical scrollbar (rightly, in my opinion), while in Edge there are both scrollbars.

Is there a reason for this? How can I make Edge behave in the same way as Chrome does?

Thanks!

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container3 {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried -ms-overflow-style https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-ms-overflow-style

Comment: @GuillaumeHarari yes, but this doesn't help me

Comment: as for the reason: different browser(engines) interpret the html and css however they want. For the most part they do generate very similar results, but it's not guaranteed. (IE is/was notorious for this)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts I have found a workaround by removing `align-items: flex-start` and replacing `display: flex` with `display: inline-flex`. Here's the new code:

```css
.container1 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.container2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.container3 {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is happening:

- When the overflow is triggered (because `height: 200px` on the `.content` element is taller than the `max-height: 150px` on the parent), a vertical scrollbar is generated.
- This scrollbar actually takes up width. The `.content` element is set to `width: 500px`. But once the scrollbar is generated, the width increases to 517px in Chrome. Note that scrollbar width varies among browsers.
- Chrome appears to factor in or just ignore the vertical scrollbar width. It refrains from launching a horizontal scrollbar. **Edge seems to consider the vertical scrollbar width as an overflow, and therefore launches the horizontal scrollbar.**
- There could be any number of reasons for this difference in behavior, including a different order of rendering elements and objects.

One thing is clear, if you move the `width: 500px` from the `.content` to the parent, the horizontal scroll problem is solved.

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.container3 {
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 500px; /* new */
}

.content {
  /* width: 500px; */
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**jsFiddle demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/yvqscf6z/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I figured the cause was what you explained in your answer, but I honestly didn't want to believe it. Anyway I can't set the width on the parent because in the real case, instead of `.content` div, I have a table without fixed sizes and `.container3` has `max-width: 100%`. So my problem is still here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `overflow-y: auto;`

Link : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

Comment: I need both overflow... the problem is that in my case only the vertical one should be showned